# Variables are not getting mapped under Variable binding (API Test)

Tags: web-services, katalon-studio

Katalon Studio Version: 5.9.1

Steps to reproduce:

I am working on API Tests using Katalon.

I created a REST request and called that in my test case. I also have couple of variables in my request body, which I am trying to parameterize from Data File.

I have added the variables under Variables tab in the Request Object.

When I create a test suite and add the test case under test suite, in the Data Binding section, variables are not getting mapped with the test data columns.

Expected Behavior:

The variables should be mapped with the test data sheet columns.

Actual Behavior:

Test Data are not getting mapped with data sheet columns.

Note - I am not able to attach the screenshots because of restrictions in office network, but I can help with details if required.

Comment: Got it resolved. I missed adding Variables under the test case.